# How to add new date format into Sitecore WebForms For Marketers (WFFM) date picker?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Is it possible in WFFM 2.4 to add own date format to date picker field? For design reasons we want format dd/MM/yy but I didn't find how to add another option to the the dropdown with available formats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new item of template type `/sitecore/templates/Web Forms for Marketers/Meta Data/Extended List Item` in the following location:

`/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Meta data/Date Formats`

It should then appear in the list of available formats.

Note however that although there is a "value" field on the item, it does not seem to be used, instead the droplist appears to use the item name. Just to be sure, set them all to the same value :)

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this, however, as you mention, Value field is ignored, so my problem is not really solved. I don't want to risk creating Sitecore item with name "dd/MM/yy"

Comment: I would raise a support ticket with Sitecore, since it should work and by default Sitecore (rightly) disallows "/" in item names.

Comment: @lekso I double checked, it appears the value field is correctly used in the front-end when rendered, just the item name is used when selecting from the droplist in the form editor. So more a UX issue than a bug.

Comment: @lekso: I found this is inconvenient too. Hence, I inherited this class and removed the [VisualFieldType(typeof (DateFormatField))] attribute out of the DateFormat property so that I could input my desired format in plain text. Turns out, the dateformat takes the item name of the Date Formats item, not the 'value' field value. So weird! I am using WFFM MVC 8 btw.

Comment: @HarryNinh I didn't get a chance, but you should raise this as a bug with Sitecore if you can. Seems silly as it is currently implemented.

Comment: @HarryNinh Thanks, I'll have a look at your solution. I ended up creating a new field type which inherits from single line input field. Does the job for us.